# Is there a way to get the FULL description of a package from the Package Manager console

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

When running the command

```
Get-Package -Remote StructureMap-MVC3
```

In the Package Manager Console for NuGet, it returns the following with the descriptions for the packages truncated.

```
Id                                                                                  Version                                                                             Description                                                                        
--                                                                                  -------                                                                             -----------                                                                        
StructureMap-MVC3                                                                   1.0.1                                                                               Adds the latest version of structuremap and configures it as the default Depende...
StructureMap-MVC3                                                                   1.0.2                                                                               Adds the latest version of structuremap and configures it as the default Depende...
```

Is there a way to  query the full description of the package from the console?

Comment: You should probably use `Find-Package {package name}` command now as `Get-Package -Remote` has been deprecated and will be removed.

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can if you write something like this:

```
Get-Package -Remote StructureMap-MVC3 | fl
```

By default we show results in a concise way so more things fit in a smaller space fl (short for format list) will show the properties in a details view.

Comment: Is it not possible to have auto-sizing of all three columns namely `Id`, `Versions` and `Description` keeping the tabular output intact instead of going for list view?

Comment: Is there any other additional parameter to the command `Get-Package | ft -AutoSize` which I can use so that all three output columns get expanded in table view itself. I don't mind if that results in a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 15):

You can get the standard output, with the first column sized to fit like this:

`Get-Package | ft -AutoSize`

It will ensure all the information you need is visible.

Comment: It doesn't formats all columns. Only the first column as you have mentioned. OP particularly has problem in viewing the full description which is the third column in the output.

Comment: This should happen by default.  Or the default for the first column should be wider.  Most package names are cut off and that is the main point of the command to begin with.