# How to adjust or format the column width in output of Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

I ran below command in Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

```
Find-Package analysisservices
```

This command gives below output:

[image]

For several packages whose name is relatively longer than the width of the `Id` column it shows three dots `...` in the end. It doesn't show any tool-tip when I hover mouse over the long names having three dots `...`.

Is there any way to adjust the width of the displayed columns so that long names don't get truncated?

**Update**: One thing which is still not solved. Is there any other additional parameter to the command `Get-Package | ft -AutoSize` which I can use so that all three output columns get expanded in table view itself. I don't mind if that results in a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try formatting the output stream like this

```
Find-Package analysisservices | ft -AutoSize
```

More information about [formatting in Powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view)

Comment: Yep. This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I got another related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052978/465053) which talks about command `Find-Package analysisservices | fl` which gives even more friendly output.

Comment: Is there any other additional parameter to the command `Get-Package | ft -AutoSize` which I can use so that all three output columns get expanded in table view itself. I don't mind if that results in a horizontal scroll bar. Currently it expands only the first column `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is to add additional details to complement [Emiel Koning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44983423/465053).

I came across another output format for `Find-Package` command. With the help of this format, we can display only desired columns on the output console. `Find-Package` command displays three columns by default namely `Id`, `Name` and `Description`. On various general purpose monitors, there isn't enough space to display all three columns completely.

When the number of displayed columns is less then each column gets more space on the console output. Hence, the dots `...` go away automatically. Here is the command format -

```
Find-Package analysisservices | Format-Table -Property Id,Versions
```

It returns below output:

[image]

If we want to see only `Id` and `Description` columns then we can use below command:

```
Find-Package analysisservices | Format-Table -Property Id,Description
```

**Note**: `ft` is an alias for `Format-Table` argument. It is *not* case-sensitive. So all the commands mentioned below are equivalent and will give same output:

```
Find-Package analysisservices | Format-Table -Property Id,Versions
Find-Package analysisservices | FT -Property Id,Versions
Find-Package analysisservices | ft -Property Id,Versions
Find-Package analysisservices | Ft -Property Id,Versions
Find-Package analysisservices | fT -Property Id,Versions
```